# What is meaning of mode bits in open function?

Tags: c, linux, header-files

In this header `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-38/include/uapi/asm-generic/fcntl.h` , I've found following defintions:

```
#define O_ACCMODE 00000003
#define O_RDONLY  00000000
#define O_WRONLY  00000001
#define O_RDWR    00000002
#ifndef O_CREAT
#define O_CREAT      00000100 /* not fcntl */
...
```

1. What are difference between `opening mode` and `setting flag`? Mode is `O_*` and flag `S_*`, but both can be write/read-only in open(2) method.
2. What kind of numeric system is `O_ACCMODE 00000003`, is it octal?, so it can have values between `0-7`?, then maximum number is `77777777`? (I am beginner)
3. last one - can I make my custom flags/mode in specific access of files? The first flag `O_ACCMODE` is not in documentation in open(2) (why), does that mean, I cannot use it in that method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2. Yes, those are octal numbers. To use octal literals, we use 0 (zero) as a prefix with the number.

Comment: 1. The `O_*` flags indicate the mode of a handle.  See `open`'s `flags` argument for an example. The  `S_*` are used for permissions. See `open`'s `mode` argument for an example.

Comment: 2. Yes, numeric literals starting with `0` are octal. The max will vary based on the size of `unsigned int`.

Comment: @ikegami, so the maximum number that can be used for a flag defined in that header is `77777777`? It is left for some special purpose?

Comment: 3. `O_ACCMODE` is a mask to used to isolate certain bits. It doesn't make sense to provide this to `open`.

Comment: Re "*so the maximum number that can be used for a flag defined in that header*", huh? What are you asking?

Comment: @ikegami. I am probably misunderstood, but `O_*` is `creation flag` in open(2), but in that header `<asm/fcntl.h>`, those are not creation flag, but modes, or? Because, in header `<asm/fcntl.h>` is for example `O_RDONLY` flag, which is in open(2) as `S_IRUSR` mode, (there is no `O_RDONLY` in documentation otherwise). Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: Re "*Do I understand it correctly?*", I doubt it, because you say things like "*`O_RDONLY` flag, which is in open(2) as `S_IRUSR` mode*" which make absolutely no sense. It it says `S_IRUSR`, you can't claim it talking about `O_RDONLY`! Certain flags can be used for certain parameters of certain syscalls. Read the docs of the syscall to see which flags can/must be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are difference between opening mode and setting flag? Mode is `O_*` and flag `S_*`, but both can be write/read-only in open(2) method.

The manpage explains it: `O_*` constants go into the `flags` parameter (with some restrictions), `S_*` constants go into the `mode` parameter (only used in some cases, like when passing `O_CREAT` etc.).

It is best to study the man pages and the different standards before trying to understand kernel or libc code.

> What kind of numeric system is `O_ACCMODE 00000003`, is it octal?, so it can have values between 0-7?, then maximum number is `77777777`?

Yes, numbers starting with `0` followed by a digit are in octal. This is defined by the C standard.

The maximum integer would be `INT_MAX` in C. Although there is no need for that when using `open`.

> can I make my custom flags/mode in specific access of files?

No, you should not make custom ones.

> The first flag `O_ACCMODE` is not in documentation in open(2) (why), does that mean, I cannot use it in that method?

That flag is defined by POSIX and is a mask to retrieve the access modes. You are not supposed to pass it to `open`, so it is not documented there.

Comment: Well, I do not know, whether reading system headers is *studying kernel*, but just want to know, what headers offer. I can read man pages for some common function and try to use them, but that won't tell me, how it works. Also, I usually need some examples, to demonstrate the usage

Comment: Also, what do you mean by *different standards*, the standard documented in man pages is not only one? What is the purpose of having many standards for one language?

Comment: @autistic456 That header is provided by the kernel, you are not supposed to include it yourself nor care about its contents as a user (of course, you can read it, but it is not the best way to understand/learn if you are starting out). The manpages are what describes the functions and its usage. If you are learning and want some examples, a good way to find them is to search for questions about using the functions.

Comment: @autistic456 The standards I was referring to aren't about languages. `open` is not a C function, but a POSIX one. If you want to use the standard library from C, you should use `fopen` (which is simpler, more portable and you will find more examples about it! :).